# Set to input width auto on .animate jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Is possible to set width auto on animate? for example :

```
 $(this).animate({width: "400px"}, 'slow');
```

I already tried this method but is not working.

Comment: `$('body').width('auto').animate({width: "400px"}, 'slow');`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to set .animate width on auto for all input fields that has a value bigger that input width

Comment: Can you show the markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better way to give auto width to an input is the to ad the input into a div and set auto to animate on div and input. For me it worked.